# Canonical angle between two subspaces and singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

I saw the statement "Given two subspaces $\mathbf{V}_1$, $\mathbf{V}_2 \subseteq \Re^d$, then the canonical angles between the subspaces $\mathbf{V}_1$ and $\mathbf{V}_2$ is given by the singular values of $\mathbf{V}_1'\mathbf{V}_2$.

Where can I find the proof for the above ?.

Comment: The introduction of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0523.pdf might contain what you are looking for. Besides that, searching on google yielded a lot of results.

Comment: @James it does not contain proof. It just mention the theorem and a reference. To be very specific, in the referenced articles, (e.g. http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/na/m/92/13/NA-M-92-13.pdf) they say the canoncal correlations are the singular values of the product of two orthogonal matrices.  Product of two orthogonal matrix is another orthoginal matrix, and all the singular values should be one right ?. Which means all the angles are 90 ?

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry that my comment wasn't too helpful. You will find a full proof in *Numerical Methods for Computing Angles Between Linear Subspaces* by Björck and Golub. It is available [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2005662?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). The statement you are searching for is Theorem 1 of section 3. I also recommend to read the short introduction to this section. I hope this helps you and sufficiently answers your question.